# JsTree with dnd plugin, always copy

Tags: jstree, drag-and-drop

I have 2 trees using jsTree and dnd plugin.
I want that each drag operation to be a copy instead of a move.
There is a "copy_modifier" which works Ok when pressing a modifier key, but I want copy to be the default behavior without the modifier.
Any ideas?

Thanks,
Adrian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution on http://groups.google.com/group/jstree
I added the following section when configuring jsTree:
"crrm": {
            "move": { "always_copy": "multitree" }
        }

Hope this helps,
Adrian

Answer (score 3):

another solution for the new version. it works, but not fully tested.

```
"core": {
    "check_callback": function (operation, node, node_parent, node_position, more) {
        if (more) {
            if (more.is_multi) {
                more.origin.settings.dnd.always_copy = true;
            } else {
                more.origin.settings.dnd.always_copy = false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adrian's solution won't work with the new versions. 
There's that dnd plugins always copy flag
[dnd.always_copy](http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=$.jstree.defaults.dnd.always_copy)

Setting this flag will make all drag and drops copy operations instead of move. But if you are looking for a solution where you need internal tree elements to be moved on dnd but inter tree dnds to be copies than here's a hack:

- Keep a global variable flag on your page
- Handle copy_node.jstree events and update your global flag from
  data.is_multi (data is the second arg of the event function)
- Implement [check_callback](http://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=$.jstree.defaults.core.check_callback) function and if operation is delete_node and your flag is set unset your flag and return false, preventing deletion from the dnd.