# jstree - enabling copy operation between trees disables the move operation inside one tree

Tags: drag-and-drop, jstree, jstree-dnd

I have 2 jstrees. TreeSource and TreeDestination. I want only the copy operation to be enabled while moving the nodes between trees. In my TreeDestination I have the below line inside `check_callback`.

```
if (more) {
            more.origin.settings.dnd.always_copy = true;
          }
```

Now, many of the cases work fine with this. That is, the copy operation takes place between the nodes when dragging them from one tree to another and vice versa. However, now when I move the nodes of tree TreeSource inside the tree itself, they are not moved, but getting copied. Looks like `more.origin.settings.dnd.always_copy = true;` is affecting both the trees, despite declaring only in the TreeDestination.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Are you intended to set more.origin.settings.dnd.always_copy to true, or testing to see whether it it true or not? The statement in your question above will override whatever it is currently set to, to true and therefore always copy.

Comment: Also check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734680/jstree-with-dnd-plugin-always-copy?rq=1